# Oracle SQL Update using group by/case

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a record table1 with structure like

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 EMPLID ENRCD ADDL_SEQ ...

with (KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 EMPLID ENRCD ADDL_SEQ) being keys
```

I have rows where EMPLID & ERNCD are same but different values of KEY1/2/3
I would like to increment ADDL_SEQ value by 1 when multiple rows exist for same EMPLID & ERNCD

example

```
 - KEY1   KEY2 KEY3  EMPLID  ERNCD ADDL_SEQ
   001    A1   B1    12345   REG    1
   001    A1   B2    12345   REG    2

UPDATED SQL
UPDATE PS_XX_PY40_APAY_1 A1
SET A1.ADDL_SEQ =
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY XX_EMPLOYEE_ID,ERNCD ORDER BY 
    XX_CONVERSION_ID,XX_UCPATH_LOC,XX_WRKR_INSTANCE,XX_APPT_NUM,XX_DIST_NUM,EMPL_RCD,EMPLID,EFFDT)
    FROM PS_XX_PY40_APAY_1 B1
    WHERE B1.XX_EMPLOYEE_ID=A1.XX_EMPLOYEE_ID 
    and B1.ERNCD=A1.ERNCD
    AND XX_CONVERSION_ID=XX_CONVERSION_ID 
    AND XX_UCPATH_LOC=XX_UCPATH_LOC  
    AND A1.XX_WRKR_INSTANCE=B1.XX_WRKR_INSTANCE
    AND B1.XX_APPT_NUM=A1.XX_APPT_NUM  
    AND B1.XX_DIST_NUM=A1.XX_DIST_NUM  
    AND A1.EMPLID=B1.EMPLID  
    AND A1.EMPL_RCD=B1.EMPL_RCD 
    AND A1.EFFDT=B1.EFFDT
);
```

WHERE all the keys are joined. However, the results are not as desired

Result

```
004720864   RGN 1
004720864   RGN 1
004720864   RGN 1
004720864   RGN 1
```

Expected

```
   004720864    RGN 1
    004720864   RGN 2
    004720864   RGN 3
    004720864   RGN 4
```

Comment: `B1.ERNCD=A1.ERNCD` ... typo for `B1.ENRCD=A1.ENRCD`

Comment: Opps. Thank you. But it did not work. Please see updated results. The other KEYs need not match, but the XX_EMPLOYEE_ID and ERNCD should for incrementing ADDL_SEQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `update` statement, and the one suggested in Tim's answer, is that they don't take into account that the `rank` or `row_number` analytic function gets computed ***after*** the `where` clause has already been applied.  So, in effect, the analytic function is computed on a single row, which will obviously always return `1`. Definitely not what you want.

Here is a way to perform the update using the `merge` statement that should work for you:

```
merge into table1 dest
using (
  select key1, key2, key3, emplid, enrcd,
         row_number() over (partition by emplid, enrcd
                                order by key1, key2, key3) as addl_seq
    from table1
) src
on (
  src.key1 = dest.key1
  and src.key2 = dest.key2
  and src.key3 = dest.key3
  and src.emplid = dest.emplid
  and src.enrcd = dest.enrcd
)
when matched then
  update set dest.addl_seq = src.addl_seq
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the numbering you need

```
select KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, EMPLID, ENRCD,
       row_number() over(partition by EMPLID, ENRCD order by KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)  as ADDL_SEQ
from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select out the numberings, then the answer by @Serg should be fine.  If you want to update your actual table, then the following should work:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET t1.ADDL_SEQ =
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLID, ENRCD ORDER BY KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.EMPLID = t1.EMPLID AND
          t2.ENRCD  = t1.ENRDC AND
          t2.KEY1   = t1.KEY1 AND
          t2.KEY2   = t1.KEY2 AND
          t2.KEY3   = t1.KEY3
)
```

If the `ADDL_SEQ` column does not yet exist, you can create it via:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD ADDL_SEQ int;
```

Comment: @user5702606 Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`

Comment: Same result. ADDL_SEQ is not incrementing